# How can an SQL query return data from these tables?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have `TrsViewPay` view with this sample data:

```
id  DocTypeRef   TrsDocPayItemref
---------------------------------
1      10            16
2      20            17
3      30            18
4      40            1
```

First I don't want to show record with DocTypeRef 40.

Then I don't want to show the records where the id is equal with that record's `TrsDocPayItemref`.

So I want to show this result (without record 1 and 4)

```
id  DocTypeRef   TrsDocPayItemref
---------------------------------
2      20            17
3      30            18
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ravi's answer is close, but I think this one will be better:

```
SELECT Id, DocTypeRef, TrsDocPayItemref
FROM TrsViewPay 
WHERE DocTypeRef <> 40
AND Id <> (SELECT TrsDocPayItemref FROM TrsViewPay WHERE DocTypeRef = 40)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can go for inner queries or sub queries. You can first Select the value of 
DocTypeRef and then compare it with id. use first point as inner query. After that you can retrieve data using the result of first query.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TrsViewPay 
WHERE DocTypeRef!=40 
      AND NOT TrsDocPayItemref IN (SELECT id FROM TrsViewPay )
```

Comment: I'd like to Alter the view, and this result show in the result of this view

Comment: this query does not show anything

I have View , I want to Alter this View to achive  Result.